# Executing Javascript in WebBrowser Control stopped working after upgrade to Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, webbrowser-control

**BACKGROUND:**  The following works in Access 2007, but broke when I installed 2010

I have a WebBrowser control in an Access Form;  I set its location as follows

```
Me.WebBrowser0.ControlSource = "http://website.com"
```

and then execute a script in the page

```
Script = "StartScript(null);"
Me.WebBrowser0.Object.Document.parentWindow.execScript Script, "JavaScript"
```

This worked just fine in Access 2007, but immediately after installing 2010 I got the following pop-up error:

```
Run-Time error '-2147024891 (80070005)':
Access is Denied.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you checked the permissions when you changed the file?

Comment: There was no change other than installing office 2010

Comment: Is IE upgraded when you install Office? Or if IE is not upgraded, is the mdb file moved to a different IE security zone?

Comment: Good Q; IE not upgraded, not sure how to find if mdb file, which is on local drive, is not in different IE security zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WORKAROUND:**

Not sure why the following works, but it does.
Web page saved locally to hard drive, added the following line to the beginning of the file

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

Disabled protected mode;
Changed Me.WebBrowser0.ControlSource to

```
Me.WebBrowser0.ControlSource = "file://T:/foo.html"
```